# Why glGetTexImage2D(GL_LUMINANCE) from an RGBA texture only returns the red components?

Tags: opengl

I'm learning legacy OpenGL and found that `glGetTexImage2D(GL_LUMINANCE)` from an RGBA image only returns the red components as result.

According to some manual pages, I expect the result to be `R+G+B`.

This is even a [test case](https://github.com/mesa3d/piglit/blob/6622348f7e0068e9d37dd540a107da33447d0ddf/tests/texturing/getteximage-luminance.c#L136) for Mesa 3D.

Why’s it works this way? I look through the OpenGL spec but cannot found a description matching this behavior.

Update:

Also, `glCopyTexImage2D(GL_LUMINANCE)` only copies the red component as luminance from an RGBA frame buffer, which seems related. I don't understand this too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml):

> GL_LUMINANCE
>
> Each element is a single luminance value. The GL converts it to floating point, then assembles it into an RGBA element by replicating the luminance value three times for red, green, and blue and attaching 1 for alpha. Each component is then multiplied by the signed scale factor GL_c_SCALE, added to the signed bias GL_c_BIAS, and clamped to the range [0,1]

So when uploading, you upload a single channel image. It makes sense that you would get the same thing back when downloading the image from the GPU.

In the code you linked to, in `test_fbo_readpixels_lum_as_rgba()`, the uploaded luminance image is a 2x2 image where each pixel contains 0.25. They then download the image as RGBA and expect to get back  4 pixels each containing (0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0). This matches what you're seeing and what the above documentation says.